# Merging layers in cost distance analysis to account for other variables?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, cost-path, arcgis-10.6

For example, say I was rafting down a river but there was a small bridge in the way. That would significantly change the difficulty but not necessarily stop the progress.

Is there a way for me to include polygon layers (from a buffer) or lines or points into the cost path to represent a change in terrain?

I'm using ArcMap 10.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your features have a populated cost field, then convert your feature class to a raster.

Eg:

- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-to-raster.htm
- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/conversion-toolbox/polygon-to-raster.htm
- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/conversion-toolbox/polyline-to-raster.htm
- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/conversion-toolbox/point-to-raster.htm

(Note that the last three require either 3D Analyst, Spatial Analyst or Advanced license.)

Be sure to use a consistent cell size and snap raster.